# BEN notation replacing "--" with "_" affecting Lightning Design Tokens also?

Tags: css, slds, style, design-tokens, bemnotation

In Spring 21 BEM notations with "--" are being deprecated and should be replaced with "_" (eg "slds-m-right--xx-small" will become "slds-m-right_xx-small"), will this effect Lightning Design System Design Tokens (eg "--lwc-spacingXSmall" to become "_lwc-spacingXSmall")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this change does not affect tokens or anything else. Only SLDS classes, including SLDS overrides in CSS, SLDS included in literal markup, and SLDS classes in strings in JavaScript, are affected. You should continue to use design tokens as they always have been.